# Do I need to use Shared Preferences if I want to retrieve data of the user after the user login?

Tags: android

I am currently learning to develop a mobile application using Android Studio. I have successfully done for the login activity. I would like to know whether I have to use Shared Preferences if I want to retrieve the data of the user after they login ?

Comment: Elaborate the question a bit more and also give a context of the app or project. Also, what do you expect from an answer to the question?

Comment: I'm sorry.. Basically what I'm trying to do is to build an application where the user is the staff of the company. As for now, after the user login, he/she will be able to see their profile and their salary details. From what I learn by myself, Shared Preference is to store a little bit of the users data. I would like to know if I want to retrieve all of the users data (their profile and salary details) , it is a must for me to use Shared Preference ?

Answer (score 0):

To store user data, the best way is to set them in a user model like below:

```
public class User {

private int user_isd;
private long post_count;
private long follower_count;
private long following_count;
private String user_email;
private String user_tag;
private String user_register_type;
private String user_mobile;
private String user_picture;
private String user_name;
private String user_bio;
private String user_gender;
private String user_latitude;
private String user_longitude;
private String user_location_name;
private String user_skills;
private int is_follow;
private String token;
private boolean isLoggedIn;

public User() {
}

public String getUser_email() {
    return user_email;
}

public void setUser_email(String user_email) {
    this.user_email = user_email;
}

public String getUser_tag() {
    return user_tag;
}

public void setUser_tag(String user_tag) {
    this.user_tag = user_tag;
}


public String getUser_mobile() {
    return user_mobile;
}

public void setUser_mobile(String user_mobile) {
    this.user_mobile = user_mobile;
}


public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}

public String getUser_bio() {
    return user_bio;
}

public void setUser_bio(String user_bio) {
    this.user_bio = user_bio;
}

public String getUser_gender() {
    return user_gender;
}

public void setUser_gender(String user_gender) {
    this.user_gender = user_gender;
}

public int getUser_isd() {
    return user_isd;
}

public void setUser_isd(int user_isd) {
    this.user_isd = user_isd;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public int getIs_follow() {
    return is_follow;
}

public void setIs_follow(int is_follow) {
    this.is_follow = is_follow;
}

public String getUser_picture() {
    return user_picture;
}

public void setUser_picture(String user_picture) {
    this.user_picture = user_picture;
}

public String getUser_latitude() {
    return user_latitude;
}

public void setUser_latitude(String user_latitude) {
    this.user_latitude = user_latitude;
}

public String getUser_longitude() {
    return user_longitude;
}

public void setUser_longitude(String user_longitude) {
    this.user_longitude = user_longitude;
}

public String getUser_location_name() {
    return user_location_name;
}

public void setUser_location_name(String user_location_name) {
    this.user_location_name = user_location_name;
}

public String getUser_skills() {
    return user_skills;
}

public void setUser_skills(String user_skills) {
    this.user_skills = user_skills;
}

public long getPost_count() {
    return post_count;
}

public void setPost_count(long post_count) {
    this.post_count = post_count;
}

public long getFollower_count() {
    return follower_count;
}

public void setFollower_count(long follower_count) {
    this.follower_count = follower_count;
}

public long getFollowing_count() {
    return following_count;
}

public void setFollowing_count(long following_count) {
    this.following_count = following_count;
}


public String getUser_register_type() {
    return user_register_type;
}

public void setUser_register_type(String user_register_type) {
    this.user_register_type = user_register_type;
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return isLoggedIn;
}

public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    isLoggedIn = loggedIn;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [user_email = " + user_email + ", user_tag = " + user_tag + ", user_isd = " + user_isd + ", user_mobile = " + user_mobile + ", user_picture = " + user_picture + ", following_count = " + following_count + ", user_name = " + user_name + ", user_bio = " + user_bio + ", user_gender = " + user_gender + ", post_count = " + post_count + ", follower_count = " + follower_count + "]";
}
```

}

Then you can store that model in Sqlite Database Table or you can use a Room ORM Database also.
Shared Preference is used to store single values. But in case you have multiple values for user, you need to store that in database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Shared Preference to store user's **basic details**(If it's not more complicated) like user id, display name and etc. And on logout of user, you need to clear all that stored informations.

You can consider below class as an example:

```
public class UserPrefManager {
    private static final String is_LOGIN = "is_user_login";
    private static final String USER_ID = "user_id";

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    private static final String MyPREFERENCES = "myPrefs";

    public UserPrefManager(Context context) {
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setIsLogin(boolean value) {
        pref.edit().putBoolean(is_LOGIN, value).apply();
    }

    public boolean isLogin() {
        return pref.getBoolean(is_LOGIN, false);
    }

    public void setUserId(String value) {
        pref.edit().putString(USER_ID, value).apply();
    }

    public String getUserId(String defValue) {
        return pref.getString(USER_ID, defValue);
    }

    public void setBooleanValue(String key, Boolean value) {
        pref.edit().putBoolean(key, value).apply();
    }

    public boolean getBooleanValue(String key, Boolean defValue) {
        return pref.getBoolean(key, defValue);
    }

    public boolean clear() {
        return pref.edit().clear().commit();
    }

}
```